# Rails 3.2: session variable gets lost in view helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session

Here is the definition of a method in a custom helper file:

```
def return_customers_by_access_right
  access_rights = session[:user_privilege].action_rights_top('index', FixedTaskProjectx.customer_class.to_s.underscore.pluralize)
  return [] if access_rights.blank? or access_rights.sql_code.blank?
  return instance_eval(access_rights.sql_code)  #instance_eval(access_rights.sql_code) #.present?
end
```

The error is:

```
undefined local variable or method `session' for FixedTaskProjectx::ProjectxHelper:Module
```

In debug, right before calling the method, the `session[:user_privilege]` exists. However when the method gets called and executed, the`session[]`becomes undefined and lost. This method is called in views to generate a list of customers for a collection. What could cause this kind of problem?

Comment: @vinodadhikary is that true? i don't have a problem accessing the session in the view or helper layer

Comment: According to our test, the session is lost even calling directly from a controller.

Comment: solved the session lost problem by moving the method into application controller.