# undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass in RSpec Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

There is the following helper for my specs in Rails:

```
include ApplicationHelper

def sign_in(user)
  session[:access_token] = user.access_token
end

def signed_in?
  current_user.present?
end

def current_user
  User.find_by(access_token: session[:access_token])
end
```

But I've got "undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass". How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no `session` method reference here, so the problem must be elsewhere. You should share your stacktrace and any code associated with it.

Comment: I just need to set session in my specs, because my controllers use it. How can I set session variables in RSpec?

Comment: You're already setting the `session` variable, but that's not your problem. You're sending `session` to `nil` someplace in your controller (e.g. `foo.session` where `foo` evaluates to `nil`).

Comment: What kind of helper is that? How do you use it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the context of which you are calling these methods from. A session generally exists in the controller. If you were to call one of these methods from a class then there would Class backing the method call. Right now there is a nil class calling the session method. You need to be in the proper context of a session to access the session.

Note the different context here:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  #NOTE: within the context of a class in this case class PagesController

  include ApplicationHelper

  def some_method
    sign_in(user)
  end
end
```

If you wrap the method call in a class context like this:

```
class Utility
  include ApplicationHelper
  def self.sign_in_a_user(user)
    sign_in(user)
  end
end
```

Then the error makes more sense:

```
undefined local variable or method `session' for Utility:Class
```

Anyways! `nil:NilClass` is the context you are in.

See similar questions:

[Access session in Helper file ? Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774257/access-session-in-helper-file-rails-3)